# FAILED_PRECONDITION error while hitting the Google people API to retrieve contacts

Tags: google-people-api

We are working on a contact sync solution to be able to sync contacts from Google contacts to other apps.

We are using a polling mechanism that runs the [people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#http-request) endpoint every 5 mins to retrieve the latest created/updated contacts. After we retrieve any data from the above endpoint, we use the refreshed syncToken (`nextSyncToken`) in our next API call.

We are getting a 400 error with a message `Sync token is expired. Clear local cache and retry call without the sync token.` before the expiry of the syncToken. I am aware of the syncToken validity period being 7days. But I sometimes experience this issue on the same day after retrieving the new syncToken.

Am I missing any hidden API limitations from the Google People API?

```
{"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Sync token is expired. Clear local cache and retry call without the sync token.",
"status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"}}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the relevant parts of the code you're using?

Comment: This behavior is very random at the moment. Below is the basic curl request.



`curl --location --request GET 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?pageSize=100&personFields=names&requestSyncToken=true&syncToken=MisAPB3nNAAABIIop_pyK2K8QIQp-7hzqKK8QLpwbBZ7JUPLfaAXhBH104SOgw4MDUwNjA5Njg3NjI=' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.a0AfH6SMC1FNy4KEheVmw1CQODftVkCVTdytMDeyVIOgO6RotXRRR7cD1FJgVAkm-g-k3z7J5Dgoylqto9uWDhVHwxXOSBFZnAxSjEKwKS--58dMQK_WJknyJfIzzt09EaagQm-PTymuvD6TtQu_4yRwrHhPmqQ'`

Comment: So, is there a way of reliably reproducing this? If that's the case, can you provide the corresponding reproduction steps?

Comment: The cause for this error is still unknown. Hence, it is not clear for us how to reproduce this error.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this for now. I set up a time-driven trigger to call this method using the `syncToken`, and after 4 days it hasn't shown any error. I'll keep it on a few more days and see how it evolves.

Comment: When I tried to reproduce this, the message `Sync token is expired. Clear local cache and retry call without the sync token.` started showing up after about a week, working as expected. In case you find a way to reliably reproduce this, I'd suggest reporting it in Issue Tracker. Otherwise, please consider contacting [Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) if you are still experiencing this.

Comment: I am still not able to reproduce this issue. I will monitor this API for a few more days and get back to the support directly if I have any issues.